# pip doesn't install the lastest vertion of a package

Tags: python, pip, version, pypi

I'm trying to install the latest version (`0.0.7`) of the package https://pypi.org/project/revolutionhtl/ using the command

`pip install revolutionhtl`

After running this command, the installed version is `0.0.4`. Bellow you can see the output of the command, please note that the third line says `Using cached revolutionhtl-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)`, so it seems that pip detects version `0.0.7`, nevertheless, it is not installed.

```bash
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting revolutionhtl
  Using cached revolutionhtl-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting networkx>=2.8
  Using cached networkx-3.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.22.3
  Using cached numpy-1.24.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.63.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from revolutionhtl) (4.64.0)
Collecting pandas>=1.4.2
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.1 MB)
Collecting revolutionhtl
  Using cached revolutionhtl-0.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached revolutionhtl-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached revolutionhtl-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Installing collected packages: revolutionhtl
Successfully installed revolutionhtl-0.0.4
```

Also, I tried with the command `pip install revolutionhtl==0.0.7`, obtaining as output:

```bash
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting revolutionhtl==0.0.7
  Using cached revolutionhtl-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools (from revolutionhtl) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for itertools
```

What should I do to install version `0.0.7`?

My python version: 3.10.9.

```bash
$ pip --version
pip 22.3 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Since revolutionhtl requires python >= 3.7, the problem shouldn't be my python

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and does revolutionhtl v0.0.7 support it?

Comment: Python version: 3.10.9. pip --version = pip 22.3 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10). Since revolutionhtl requires python >= 3.7, the problem shouldn't be my python

Comment: Run `pip` with `-vv` to get more details about it's decisions.

Comment: @KlausD. That flag didn't output anything helpful for me. Here you can see it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s-0JF8xKIYJPN-Xeh7Rsg5XfSTau_u31/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the package creator. We saw that **the problem was the dependency list of the package**. The following was specified in the `pyproject.toml` file:

```
dependencies = [
    "networkx >= 2.8",
    "pandas >= 1.4.2",
    "argparse >= 1.1",
    "os",
    "numpy >= 1.22.3",
    "tqdm >= 4.63.0",
    "itertools",
    "collections",
    ]
```

After deleting `argparse`, `os`, `itertools`, and `collections`, the problem vanished. I guess this works because those packages are part of the python standard library, and then they don't appear in pypi.

You can see the correction in [this link](https://gitlab.com/jarr.tecn/revolutionh-tl/-/commit/60e20e4eb84d1a1195117ce01f4bfd9451cdf80b), now I can download de latest version (0.0.8) using `pip install revolutionhtl`.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that the package is being installed in a user directory where you do not have write permissions. This is why pip is defaulting to user installation.
Try using the command `pip install --user revolutionhtl==0.0.7` to install it in a user directory where you have write permissions.
Also, it seems like package 'itertools' is missing and it is required by the package 'revolutionhtl'.
Try installing itertools by running `pip install itertools` before installing revolutionhtl.
If you are still facing issues, try uninstalling any existing version of the package before installing the latest version by running `pip uninstall revolutionhtl`.

Comment: `itertools` is part of the standard lib. OP *did* run `pip install revolutionhtl==0.0.7`. And `pip` will automatically upgrade installed versions of packages.

Comment: Neither `--user` flag nor `sudo` command works. Uninstalling the package doesn't change anything, even `--upgrade` flag does not work :(

Comment: Ok maybe this can help:

   " pip uninstall revolutionhtl " and

   " pip install --no-cache-dir revolutionhtl==0.0.7 "

By trying to install the package with --no-cache-dir flag, you force it to ignore the version already installed in the cache.

Comment: Trying with `--no-cache-dir` raises the same error.